# f# equivalent of Haskell's "interact"

Tags: haskell, f#

I was just reading a little about Haskell and saw its method `interact` which implements the common pattern of reading input from stdin, applying a function to the strings, and writing the result back to stdout.  So, for example:

```
interact (map toUpper)
```

prints back everything that comes on stdin converted to uppercase.

Is there an equivalent of this already in F#/.Net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality does not exist natively, but implementing it is easy:

```
let inline interact f =
    printfn "%s" (f (System.Console.Readline()))
```

Comment: Well, that's close, if you ignore the fact that `interact` uses lazy IO. Lazy IO isn't always a great idea, but it works ok for that.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm not concerned about lazy vs strict IO (since I'd just be using it for some of the toy examples you make while learning something) but doesn't that just do a single line?  I knocked up something like:

    let rec interact f =
        if (System.Console.In.Peek() >= 0) 
        then ()
        else
            System.Console.In.ReadLine()
                |> f
                |> printfn "%s"
            interact f

Comment: @PCB - This is just a single line, for multiple lines I think something like: `let rec interact f = match (f (System.Console.Readline()) with |Some(s) -> printfn "%s" s;interact f|None->()` would be a bit better, altough it requires modifying `f` so that you can break out of the loop.

Comment: Well, the lazy IO is actually a key part of why `interact` works the way it does - it can terminate early, it can give feedback immediately on receiving input (watch out for buffering), etc. Unlike pure computations, lazy IO actually is visible in ways other than termination properties. (This is why it's often considered a bad idea.)

Comment: @Carl could you say a little more about which properties of `interact` would missing if I implemented it as basically a loop going "read a line -> apply function -> write result"?

Comment: @PCB First, you would lose the ability to do any transformation that acts on more than one line of input at a time. Second, you have to complicate the type signature a bit to allow for early termination.

Comment: @PCB You get closer to `interact` by reading all input, then passing it as a single string to the function. But that loses all of `interact`'s lazy properties that let it produce output or terminate before all input has been read.

Comment: @PCB You'd get identical behavior by having the function passed to `interact` take a lazy stream of characters and return a lazy stream of characters. Then it could read more from stdin when needed. This is more or less exactly what `interact` does, except that the lazy stream of characters is the standard `String` type.

Comment: This [F# snippet](http://fssnip.net/9P) demonstrates lazy reading from the console using Seq.initInfinite and may be close to what you want. It creates a minimal Point of Sale app in 10 lines of F#.

Comment: Thanks @PhillipTrelford.  So we could write the "not identical semantics, but close enough for little experiments" version as `let interact f = Seq.initInfinite(fun _ -> System.Console.ReadLine()) |> Seq.map f |> Seq.map (printfn "%s")`.  And then to get pretty close to identical semantics we could use `let interact f = Seq.initInfinite(fun _ -> System.Console.ReadLine()) |> f |> Seq.map (printfn "%s")`, so that the type of `f` is `seq<string> -> seq<string>`.  To be strictly identical, it would use 'Console.Read()' and `f` would be `seq<char> -> seq<char>`, but that doesn't feel as natural.

Comment: @PCB That looks like an excellent summary. Thanks for including it.